# Consuming a restful web service

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to consume an interface but I am having some difficulty here.
I am trying to set it to a xamrin list view in behind a content page

```
public class xxxApiClient : IApi
 {
        readonly string url = "http://localhost:81/ ";
        readonly IHttpService httpService;

        public xxxApiClient(IHttpService httpService)
        {
            this.httpService = httpService;
        }

        public Task<List<JobsList>> GetJobs() => httpService.Get<List<JobsList>>($"{url}JobsLists");
}
```

How ever I am not to sure how I cosume getjobs correclty I am trying the following

```
public partial class JobsPage : ContentPage ,xxxWC.Interface.IApi
{
        public xxxWC.Interface.IApi api = new ful;

          public JobsPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private Task SetItemSource()
    .   {
    .       JobListing.ItemsSource =   FuelAp
 }
```

How do I use the get jobs correctly above in the method setItemSource?.

The bit I am having hard time to understand is here.

How do I call the base GetJobs method I have already created in API Client.

```
      Task<List<JobsList>> IApi.GetJobs()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private Task SetItemSource()
     {
            JobListings.ItemsSource =await GetJobs();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
Ok based on suggestions below I updated My Code as such

```
    IHttpService httpService;
   xxxApiClient _api = newxxxApiClient(httpService);
      public JobsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private Task SetItemSource()
 {
        JobListings.ItemsSource =await GetJobs();
}
```

But i get the below error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static
>   field, method, or property
>   'JobsPage.httpService'    xxxCallManagmentAppMobile   C:\Work\xxxCallAppDev\XamForms\xxxCallManagmentApp\xxxCallManagmentAppMobile\FuelCallManagmentAppMobile\Views\JobsPage.xaml.cs  17  Active

Can someone explain why

**Edit 3**
Ok i got a bit further but still having some issues. as the main method is not awaited how do I call set SetItemSource.

```
xxxApiClient _api ;
      public JobsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ()
            SetItemSource();

    }

    private async Task SetItemSource()
 {
        JobListings.ItemsSource = await client.GetJobs();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "difficulty" rather than "ductility"? The latter is a word, but has a very specific technical meaning which would be odd here. I'm hesitant to edit as I want to respect your word choice.

Comment: Sorry Mike I suffer from poor spelling please do not hold it against me in my question.

Comment: corrected the error

Comment: Are you able to inject the IApi into the ContentPage as well?

Comment: Yes but that is what I am having trouble understanding @Nkosi

Comment: The view should not be derived from the api. the view is the client

Comment: @Nkosi can you provide an example then

Comment: Ideally what you want is a way to resolve the api client in the view using DI and then calling the client

Comment: @Nkosi tried that see my error above.

Comment: Where are you setting the `IHttpService httpService;` ? are you using xamarin.forms?

Comment: @Nkosi yes xamiran forms can you provide an example please in an answer I will mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `IApi` has been mapped to `xxxApiClient` implementation

Try resolving the service using the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) so that it is available to be used in the view

```
public partial class JobsPage : ContentPage {
    public readonly IApi client;

    public JobsPage () {
        InitializeComponent ();
        client = DependencyService.Get<IApi>();
    }

    private async Task SetItemSource() {
        JobListing.ItemsSource = await client.GetJobs();
        //...
    }
}
```

As for calling the `SetItemSource`, it is async so should be awaited. That can't be done in the constructor.

Consider creating a event that can be raised and its handler used to await the desired behavior.

```
private event EventHandler loadingData = delegate { };
private async void onLoadingData(object sender, Eventargs args) {
    JobListing.ItemsSource =   await client.GetJobs();
}
```

Full code

```
public partial class JobsPage : ContentPage {
    public readonly IApi client;

    public JobsPage () {
        InitializeComponent ();
        //resolving client
        client = DependencyService.Get<IApi>();
        //subscribing to event 
        loadingData += onLoadingData;
        //raising event
        loadingData(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private async Task SetItemSource() {
        JobListing.ItemsSource = await client.GetJobs();
        //...
    }

    private event EventHandler loadingData = delegate { };
    private async void onLoadingData(object sender, Eventargs args) {
        JobListing.ItemsSource =   await client.GetJobs();
    }
}
```

Although a custom event was created, you could just as easily used on of the event/eventhandler of the view.

All of that code should actually live inside of a view model and then bound to the view in a binding context.

Comment: @DavidB I'll take a look. I would advise you make an effort to write proper code examples when posting as these incomplete snippets you have are very confusing. They should be a [mcve]